# Using a type guard on this

Tags: typescript

I created a type guard on a generic class so I can safely use its generic member.

The way to determine the member's type is by looking at the parent's `type` field.

In the code below, I use the `type` field to decide what is the body type.

From outside the class, I can use the type guard and access the data member safely.

But when I use it inside an instance method on `this`, I get compilation errors (see the comments in the code for the exact message in each case).

Why is this happening? Are there any restrictions on narrowing the type of the `this` parameter?

```js
type BodyType1 = {
  field: string;
}

type BodyType2 = number[];

type BodyType = BodyType1 | BodyType2;


function isBodyType1(t: Message): t is Message<BodyType1> {
  return t.type === 1;
}

function isBodyType2(t: Message): t is Message<BodyType1> {
  return t.type === 2;
}

class Message<T extends BodyType = BodyType> {
  type: number;
  body: T;
  constructor(type: number, body: T) {
    this.type = type;
    this.body = body;
  }

  getBodyField() {
    const t = this;
    if (isBodyType1(t)) {
      // According to the compiler hint: const t: this & Message<BodyType1>
      return t.body.field; // Compiler error: Property 'field' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)
    }
    if (isBodyType2(t)) {
      // According to the compiler hint: const t: this & Message<BodyType1>
      return t.body[0]; // Compiler error: Property 'Body' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
    }
  }
}

const m = new Message(1, {field: 'value'})
if (isBodyType1(m)) {
  // This compiles
  console.log(m.body.field);
}

if (isBodyType2(m)) {
  // This also compiles
  console.log(m.body[0]);
}
```

Comment: `function isBodyType2(t: Message): t is Message<BodyType1>` looks suspect - copy/paste error or is that real?

Comment: Also, you never set the `type` field in `Message` how do you expect your type guards to use it?

Comment: Could you correct/improve the example here to something like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NdjDnW) which doesn't involve the issues the above two commenters pointed out?

Comment: Or maybe even [this version](https://tsplay.dev/N7P8Em) which doesn't save `this` to a new variable first?  Doesn't seem to affect things much either way and it's simpler.

Comment: Also, could you put an explicit main question here?  Sometimes people want to mainly know "why is this happening" and other times people want to mainly know "how can I work around this or do it in some other way".  Which one are you looking for?

Comment: Since your question is "why is this happening", I filed [ms/TS#47903](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47903).  I'm pretty sure this is caused by a hidden circularity, but I don't want to post an official answer until I see some response there.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. I subscribed to the issue to see how it goes. Meanwhile I'll accept Jamiec answer as it solves the issue (maybe because the new interface breaks the circularity?)

Comment: Note that your question, as asked, is "why is this happening" and not "how can I work around it".  So it doesn't look like the accepted answer addresses the question directly.  Maybe you should [edit] the question so that they match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see to sensibly do this is to have the type guards on the `BodyType` itself:

```
function isBodyType1(t: BodyType): t is BodyType1 {
  return (t as BodyType1).field != undefined;
}

function isBodyType2(t: BodyType): t is BodyType2 {
  return (t as BodyType2).length != undefined
}
```

And then to use that:

```
class Message<T extends BodyType = BodyType> {
  
  body: T;
  constructor(body: T) {
    this.body = body;
  }

  getBodyField() {
    if (isBodyType1(this.body)) {
      return this.body.field; 
    }
    if (isBodyType2(this.body)) {
      return this.body[0]; 
    }
    return null;
  }
}

const m = new Message({field:"value"})
if (isBodyType1(m.body)) {
  // This compiles
  console.log(m.body.field);
}

if (isBodyType2(m.body)) {
  // This also compiles
  console.log(m.body[0]);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=45&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gExAFXBAjFAvFA3gWACgooAzASwgBsEAuKAZ2ACdyA7AcwG4iBfIoqEixEKNACZsUNgFcAtgCMIzANoBdHoUFoRSVMJzw9aTAB9dYyOM0DCpGWwDGwcnDZRyDI5YwAKYPTe+hAAlPTAHgwWwZgExFDMEMAyzO7+UACGUUEmIQB0FNQIUACEOA4IEBRsEAia-Fp2Ds6u7p45Vv6BosFhUBGe0RJ4RCSJyalQ6VlDVvlUEJzAABal5WyV1bV8to5UWVEAshAMDBkcEAA8yFAQAB7AiwjZPTqGr5AAfCPxo1AKonoyE0JEcbiYzBkzjgzF8AKQQJCPxIJBWnjy8JAUkxIKgDT+F2A3gAYpQaL4kXEUR5SFN2h8-GiGBjRCFKX9qeMUu4mSykAUyXUoBy8SLyLTfPTjJ1eZi2cjqQkktz+st0ZiVAAGDTC+IkBqc5WTWRUKi4hr4whgthMKByKQ1ADuUGOp3OEF8uEKNFoACIAG4ZKgyCC+3ghIjiuleBnoXxyPkgeVUqAAelTUGQaqiYLkYHICwYf2tDDgCzyVDgHHjiYFRRC9VsUclMelEHENbl7Pi6cz2cyVFLUFz+cLxfBZYgFarndEWrUDZ2jRLk+n1YThJJgopISAA)

---

Having updated your question, and stating in comments that you need to use `type` field in your type checks, the main problem is you're aliasing `this` as `t` which implicitly has an `any` type. Don't do that!

You also need to introduce an interface with the `type` property so that you can use it in your type guards. This works:

```
type BodyType1 = {
  field: string;
}

type BodyType2 = number[];

type BodyType = BodyType1 | BodyType2;

interface IMessage{
    type: number
}

function isBodyType1(t: IMessage): t is Message<BodyType1> {
  return t.type === 1;
}

function isBodyType2(t: IMessage): t is Message<BodyType2> {
  return t.type === 2;
}

class Message<T extends BodyType> {
  type: number;
  body: T;
  constructor(type: number, body: T) {
    this.type = type;
    this.body = body;
  }
  getBodyField(): string | number | null {
    if (isBodyType1(this)) {
      return this.body.field; 
    }
    if (isBodyType2(this)) {
      return this.body[0]; 
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gExAFXBAjFAvFA3gWACgooAzASwgBsEAuKAZ2ACdyA7AcwG4iBfIoqEixEKNACZsUNgFcAtgCMIzANoBdHoUFoRSVMJzw9aTAB9dYyOM1F2wZaQCGAY2gBJALIQGDRxwgExCRQQhD0sorKfAKEpDJszsDkcGxQ5AxGlhgAFMD0nt6+-gCU9MBpDFBePn4QADyZ+hgAfHhEJMwQwDLMqcAAdKHYWDjomvxasfGJyanpjRK5+dVFEKUhFVWFtQ2iTeKtgR1dPX2DOiM41tGTzlSOPls1-nXIUBAAHvZsCJULkId2iE0OF5EpmJoSApRPRkJCoM4UkxmDJEnBmLkQdIwcoADRQaFIWHFNpBEjAAAW6XOBmBkHh5KpDH6hJAUlZ8ImJH8wEyADFKDRsutkewOFBzBFwRLsVQqKTglAAPRKxFsJghWgrHbIVo4SnpBlpUhQbLzPYmXJM4oko6KqCdbq9EJMlmifoUagILhQIEkLnBcgms0ZC1WK3pG0K+2O04u6mslQABg0vrJUADxydqVkcs5NyIao1cikbAgAHcnqtsuh8bhPTR6AByABujioMggTd4xVswfNxkg6GycijdpVUGQTIRcDkYHIVG8QKLcEX-SocA4I7dSA9goQxXGMSDpoHWXEI7HQInU-SUHbDDgM7nC6XQRXa43W7kO5AybUh58EAA)

Comment: I updated my question - I am interested in understanding why is this happening more than in a work around.
Also, in my specific case, there are reasons why I can't use the work around - I have to use the `type` field to select the correct type for the data member.

Comment: @daramasala see if the update is more suited to your requirements